# What is the difference between ref.NULL and ref.NULL_POINTER?

Tags: node.js, node-ffi

The Node.js library 'ref' has two predefined objects NULL and NULL_POINTER, which map to the same concept (a C/C++ null pointer). Both are Buffer objects, and the documentation doesn't actually explain what separates them.

What is the difference between a ref.NULL object and a ref.NULL_POINTER object? When are you meant to use one vs the other?

Comment: im guessing `ref.NULL` is javascript `null` and `NULL_POINTER` is 0 for the c++

Comment: Side-note: can someone with sufficient reputation create a "node-ref" tag? I'm using the node-ffi tag because node-ref is mostly meant to be used with ffi, but it's a bit misleading.

Comment: @DanielA.White Nope, the official API says they're both meant to map C/C++ null pointers.

Comment: look at the code here: https://github.com/TooTallNate/ref/blob/master/lib/ref.js - `NULL_POINTER` is using `NULL`.

Comment: it looks like its just an empty buffer

Comment: @DanielA.White Well, yes, but I don't understand where either one is meant to be used and not the other.

Comment: perhaps you should ask the project, not us.